# Simple Algebraic question

Tags: linear-algebra

The solution to a system of linear equations is (0,1).If each equation of the system is multiplied by 4 to produce a new system, is the solution to the new system (0,1),(0,4),(4,5), or another ordered pair? Explain and show your work to justify your answer.

Comment: Why not try a few experiments?  Say, solve$$x+y=3\ ,\ \ x+2y=5$$and then$$4x+4y=12\ ,\ \ 4x+8y=20\ .$$Compare solutions, then make up an example for yourself, then see if you can guess what is happening, then see if you can explain why it happens.

Comment: could you please provide a full answer.

Comment: Did you do what I suggested?  What were your results?

Comment: This is very ambiguous my friend, I can't seem to solve it, maybe you can provide another explanation of exact steps and final conclusion? Thank you very much.